# Why are the two channels of my subwoofer connected by a resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, audio

I bought a new [amplifier module](https://www.hifisound.de/Do-it-yourself-Products/Active-Modul-Amplifier/Active-Subwoofer-Plate-Amplifier/Monacor-SAM-300D-Digital-Subwoofer-Module.html) for my subwoofer and recognized that the two LFE channel inputs are directly connected on the circuit board via a resistor.
I assembled the subwoofer meanwhile and I missed to take a picture but it seems I can't stop thinking about why that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a single subwoofer so it needs a mono downmix of the stereo signal you want to play.

Comment: That was fast, thank you! Could you please elaborate a bit? I can't quite follow.

Comment: What you can't follow? The resistors average the two signals, left and right, to a single signal for the signle woofer.